# How to get the width of tkinter widget?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, width

I'm trying to assign the width of a widget (in this case a label) to a variable.

What I have so far:

```
from tkinter import *

def getwidth():
    print(lbl.bbox())

root = Tk()

lbl = Label(root, text="test text")
lbl.grid(row=0)
btn = Button(root, text="GO", command=getwidth)
btn.grid(row=1)

root.mainloop()
```

I would have assumed that `bbox()` returns the offset from top left and the width and height, however, the returned value is `{0, 0, 0, 0}`.

If someone could explain why this is and what would be the step to correctly achieve this I would be greatful.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use `bbox` against the `root` widget (upon which `grid` method was called, not the widget put inside the grid).

```
print(root.bbox())
```

But without argument, it will give root widget's bounding box. You need to specify `column`, `row` argument (of the `lbl`):

```
print(root.bbox(0, 0))
```

If the widget you want to get widget not positioned as 0/0 column/row, you need to also specify `col2`, `row2` argument.

> `grid_bbox(column=None, row=None, col2=None, row2=None)` method of
>   tkinter.Tk instance
>
> Return a tuple of integer coordinates for the bounding box of this widget controlled by the geometry manager grid.
>
> If COLUMN, ROW is given the bounding box applies from the cell with row and column 0 to the specified cell. If COL2 and ROW2 are given the bounding box starts at that cell.
>
> The returned integers specify the offset of the upper left corner in the master widget and the width and height.  (`help(root.bbox)`)

---

Alternatively you can use [`winfo_width`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_width-method) and [`winfo_height`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_height-method):

```
def getwidth():
    print(lbl.winfo_width(), lbl.winfo_height())
```

Comment: "If someone could explain why this is"

Comment: @beauxq, At the time of answering the question, I didn't know the "why this is" part, so I posted the answer with "what would be the step to correctly achieve this" part only. Now I updated the answer to include the missing part. By trying to answer the missing part, I found alternative way.

Comment: root.bbox(0,0) returns (0,0,0,0). the getWidth() method returns 1.

Comment: It might be due to attempting to measure the width of the elements before they have been rendered on the screen. Define function for measure, than use something like root.after(100, measure_function) - we use the 'after' function to execute the 'measure_function' function after a brief delay once the main loop starts. This allows the elements to be drawn on the screen before we measure their width.