# How can I trigger a Button by 'painting' over it? using tkinter's "B1-Motion"?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to make a button that will be triggered if you click and drag over it ("paint" it???).  Here was my attempt:

```
import tkinter as tk

class PaintOverWidget():

    def __init__(self, master):
        b = tk.Button(master, text="UnMark All",command=self.clicked)
        b.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.pressed)
        b.pack()

    def clicked(self):
        print('clicked')

    def pressed(*e):
        print ('painted')

root=tk.Tk()
my_gui = PaintOverWidget(root)
root.mainloop()
```

When running,  it successfully reports a click, but if I click elsewhere in the window and drag over the button, it fails to report that it has been 'painted'.

What's going wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: You only bind the event to the `Button` widget.

Answer (score 1):

> **Question**: Trigger a `Button` by 'painting' over it, using tkinter's `"<B1-Motion>"` event?

You have to use `master.bind(...` as you start the motion on the `master` widget.
Also you have to take the `event.x` and `event.y` coordinates into account.

```
import tkinter as tk


class PaintOverWidget(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, master, text):
        super().__init__(master, text=text)
        self.pack()
        master.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.on_motion)

    def bbox(self):
        # Return a bbox tuple from the `Button` which is `self`
        x, y = self.winfo_x(), self.winfo_y()
        return x, y, x + self.winfo_width(), y + self.winfo_height()

    def on_motion(self, event):
        bbox = self.bbox()

        if if bbox[0] <= event.x <= bbox[2] and bbox[1] <= event.y <= bbox[3]:
            print('on_motion at x:{} y:{}'.format(event.x, event.y))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('200x100')
    PaintOverWidget(root, text="UnMark All").mainloop()
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> on_motion at x:54 y:15
> on_motion at x:55 y:15
> on_motion at x:55 y:14
> ...
> ```

***Tested with Python: 3.5 - 'TclVersion': 8.6 'TkVersion': 8.6***

Comment: I tried different things to find solution and finally made something similar to your code. I couldn't find any other method. +1

Comment: @furas: My first attemp was using `self.bbox()` but got `(0, 0, 0, 0)`. Do you know why?

Comment: documentation on effbot.org has no information - [bbox](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.bbox-method) but this answer shows that it works only with `grid()` and you would have to check `self.master.bbox()` to get size of button and other elements inside `master`: [How to get the width of tkinter widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18461448/how-to-get-the-width-of-tkinter-widget)